# Scheduling in VB.NET Windows Form

Tags: scheduling

I have teachers who are mentors for students. The students are assigned according to the language they speak. Each teacher is assigned a language and when a new student comes, the software is supposed to assign the student to a teacher of that language. The teacher with the lowest number of assigned students should get this new student.
Anyone done this before? Or any suggestion on how to go about this?

Thanks.

I have a Language Table, a teacher table with a field of language, and a student table with a language field. Before I start on my own, wanted to have a running start with some suggestions